# How do I check sound card's bit resolution and sampling rate on Linux?

Tags: sample-rate, bit-depth, linux

I have a E-MU Tracker Pre USB sound card that supports playback at up to 24-bit resolution and 192 kHz sampling rate. It works on Linux and plays both 16bit/44.1kHz and higher-bitrate content; both from files and streaming.

However, I heard that this card only works as 16bit/44.1kHz on Linux. **How do I check the actual bit resolution and sampling rate the sound card uses?** Supposedly by starting playback and entering some command line commands to read the actual values.

---

Using [these instructions](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-do-you-check-the-samplerate-in-use-by-your-sound-card-slackware64-14-a-4175448495/) from a forum I was able to check the sample rate by doing

`cat /proc/asound/card2/pcm0p/sub0/hw_params`

I had to poke around and figure that `card2` instead of `card0` seems to be a working card on my system, but how do I know it's a `E-MU Tracker Pre USB` and not some other card, e.g. a built-in codec?

Comment: Is this a question or an answer ? You know you can answer your own questions here ?

Comment: Definitely, a question. I have added my attempts to resolve my issue, but it is not the complete answer: I still need to figure out bit resolution and know which card is which.

Answer (score 1):

This might depend on which distro you use, so you might need to tweak these commands somewhat.

If you look in /proc/asound and do a `ls -alh` in this directory, you should see a list of cards named `card0`, `card1` and so on, a few symlinks pointing to the card*n* directories, and also a file called `cards`.

If you `cat cards`, you'll get something similar to mine below:

```
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                  HDA Intel PCH at 0xa3230000 irq 128
 1 [MOXF6MOXF8     ]: USB-Audio - Yamaha MOXF6/MOXF8
                  Yamaha Corporation Yamaha MOXF6/MOXF8 at usb-0000:00:14.0-4.4.1, full speed
 2 [UR22mkII       ]: USB-Audio - Steinberg UR22mkII
                  Yamaha Corporation Steinberg UR22mkII at usb-0000:00:14.0-6.1, high speed
 3 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                  HDA NVidia at 0xa3080000 irq 17
```

The ID you see at the beginning matches the number in the various card-directories. You can verify this by going into a card*n*-directory and cat'ing the file `id`, which should give you the same name.